# generating a subtable from a csv file based on another list

Tags: r, csv

I have two CSV files. One stores a long list M such as

```
type  price
A      100
B      200
C      300
D      600
...
```

The other list N also stores a list which correlate with M in terms of "type". But the length of list N is smaller than M  For instance, it just has

```
type   Performence
D      0.5
B      0.1
```

Is there a way to quickly find the subset of M which contains the type included in N. Within the context of the above example, I need the generate a sublist from M as

```
type  price
B      200
D      600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

M <- fread("path/to/M.csv")
N <- fread("path/to/N.csv")

setkey(M, "type")
setkey(N, "type")


M[N, price]
#    type price
# 1:    B   200
# 2:    D   600
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have your files as datafames:

```
M.sub <- M[M$type %in% N$type,]
```